Dynamic relocation and address translation with base and bounds registers
In the context of dynamic relocation, where base and bounds registers are used for address translation, the real address (in physical memory) corresponding to a virtual address is
real_addr = virtual_addr + base_register_value
But what about instructions that do not manipulate memory but only move data between processor registers? For instance, in x86, what would the instructions
MOVL $128, %ebx
MOVL (%ebx), %eax

do? How could they be understood from a perspective of address translation using base and bounds?

Instructions themselves live in memory, no matter the instruction's operation.

FYI that is not the physical address and this is not really address translation. It's just an addition. The address translation will happen using segmentation and paging. Also note that MOVL (%ebx), %eax does read memory, it is not just "moving data between processor registers".

It's unclear what you mean by "base and bounds". I guess you could be talking about segment base and limit?
